# Find the limit $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{x}}{(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^{2}}} $

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{x}}{(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^{2}}}.
$$

I know that the limit is of indeterminate form type $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, but it seems using L'Hopital's rule directly does not help here.  Do I somehow use the fact that $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}=e$?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199672/difficulty-in-evaluating-a-limit-lim-x-to-infty-fracex-left1-frac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $x>1$,
$$ x^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) = x -\frac{1}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),$$
so:
$$ x-x^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{1}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right). $$
By exponentiating such identity, you get that the limit is $e^{1/2}=\color{red}{\sqrt{e}}$.