# Difficulty in evaluating a limit: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x^2}}$

Tags: limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

The limit I have to evaluate is this - 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x^2}}$$

I first checked if L'Hopital's rule applies here. The limit of both numerator and denominator is $\infty$.
But differentiating the denominator yield a even more complicated expression.

I am not getting how to approach this question using some other method. Thank you.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100531/find-the-limit-lim-x-to-infty-fracex1-frac1xx2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let $$\begin{align}y &= \frac{e^x}{\left(1 + \frac 1 x\right)^{x^2}},\\\
  \ln y &= x - x^2 \ln  \left(1 + \frac 1x\right) \\
&= x - x^2\left(\frac 1x - \frac1 {2x^2} + \frac 1 {3x^3 }+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac 12 - \frac 1 {3x} + \frac 1 {4x^2}+\cdots \rightarrow \frac 12 \end{align}$$

therefore $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac {e^x} {\left(1 + \frac 1 x\right)^{x^2}}= \sqrt e.$$

Comment: Except that it's $\sqrt e~$.

Comment: nice work @Lucian.

Comment: There's a $\frac{1}{2}$ in the second term of expansion and $\frac{1}{3}$ in the third term and so on. Thanks!

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee, thanks man. it is too early in the morning for maclaurin expansion.

Comment: Once more, you win by a couple of minutes ! No mercy for the old man ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, there is no winning. with me, you have already won. to see someone still moved by math is nice. i can only hope my interest in and enthusiasm for math will go  away as i get older.

Comment: @abel. I really admire your enthusiasm ! May I ask how old you are and what you are currently doing as studies ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, i have the privilege to teach mathematics some of the wonderful highschool students. i should be studying coveters regular polyhedra. i have only finished about half of his text in the last five or six years. that man writes so well and compact it takes long to take in. i am too ashamed to admit my age.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Define $$A= \frac{e^x}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x^2}}$$ and take logarithms of both sides; so $$\log(A)=x -x^2\log(1+\frac 1 x)$$ Now, using the fact that, by Taylor, for small $y$, $\log(1+y)=y-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}+O\left(y^4\right)$, replace $y$ by $\frac 1x$ to get $$\log(A)=x-x^2\Big(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2 x^2}+\frac{1}{3 x^3}+\cdots\Big)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3 x}+\cdots$$

Comment: Just a doubt, what does the $O$ mean?

Comment: If you did not learn it yet, it is called the big $O$ notation which describes  the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value. In simpler words, for you case, say that it collects the other terms which are less and less significant. Don't worry, you will hear soon about it and you will have plenty of assignments with that. Cheers.